# Sync problem on windows 7

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows-7, sync

I use UbuntuOne on Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7.  Everything synchronized fine for several months until a few weeks ago when UbuntuOne on Windows offered an update which I installed.  Now my files on Windows 7 no longer sync even though it recognizes my username and password.  It tries to sync and then quits.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Pull all of your files from both systems (just move them into a new folder) out of UbuntuOne's view, restart it, then re add the files. It seems like it's confused on what it has properly synched and what it has not.